# Capture two parts of the same string with PHP

Tags: php

I have a list with this structure

```
Boss: (test 23, of 2014)

Boss: (test 42, of 2015)

Boss: (test 70, of 2016)
```

How can I capture the numbers in the string and wrap then in spans? So the structure will end like this:

```
Boss: (test <span class="test_23">23</span>, of <span class="year_2014">2014<span>)

Boss: (test <span class="test_42">42</span>, of <span class="year_2014">2015<span>)

Boss: (test <span class="test_70">70</span>, of <span class="year_2016">2014<span>)
```

Comment: start with `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 2):

This function can help here

step one:

`preg_replace('# ([0-9]{2}),#','<span class="test_$1">$1</span>',$input);`

step two:

`preg_replace('# ([0-9]{4})#','<span class="year_$1">$1</span>',$input);`

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with this one-liner:

```
$input = "Boss: (test 23, of 2014)";

$output = preg_replace(
    '/Boss: \(test (\d+), of (\d{4,4})\)/',
    'Boss: (test <span class="test_$1">$1</span>, of <span class="year_$2">$2<span>)',
    $input);
```

You might want to make this fault-tolerant regarding white space, i.e. use `\s+` instead of hard coded spaces to allow for multiple whitespaces, tabs etc.